# Heapdump vs profiling memory in visual vm

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I start using visual vm , in order to find out why the app is using so much memory.

Just to be sure i understand things:

A complete memory map is aquired via the heapdump ?

With memory profiler (because only the 10 object is took into account ?) there is just an overview ?

Did I understood correctly ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you understood correctly... if you make a full snapshot of memory in visualvm, you get everything.

Comment: a full heap dump yes ==> all memory...but when i choose memory profiling it says that only then 10th object is profiled...that is why i was a little bit confused

Comment: it says 12789 classes instrumented tracking each 10th object ... ==> it might not track one that holds a lot of memory ... a buggy singleton let's say

Comment: Yes, that's hot tracking, it just can't track everything for performance/memory consumption reasons, but it allows you to see live what's going on in the app. The snapshot is the equivalent of `heapdump`.

Comment: Thanks  you should put that as response so I can marked it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VisualVM has a memory profiling mode where it continually tracks what's going on with memory allocation in your application. In this mode it can't bear the load of tracking every single object, so the compromise is to track every 10th allocation. On the other hand, there is the *Heap Dump* feature available on the Monitor tab, where you get the full details on all objects. This dump is the equivalent to the command-line `heapdump` utility.

Comment: taking a snapshot from the profiler tab only records the current state of the profiler. To get the full memory you still need to create a heapdump. (version 1.7 of visual VM )

Comment: A memory snapshot only takes a copy of what is currently visible in the memory profiler (ie. every 10th object by default)

Comment: So I just need to rename the feature I call *memory snapshot* in the answer to *Heap Dump*, which is available on the Monitor tab. Right?

Comment: yes, not sure if the terminology changed from older versions of the Visual VM but noticed your answer while looking for something else and thought i'd point it out just in case someone else is looking for this

Comment: I believe it was my imprecision when writing the answer. Thanks for the note, the answer is corrected.

Answer (score 3):

1) heapdump lets you find out, which objects are actually held by your app and consume heap

2) memory profiler shows you at which rate your app allocates objects (+their class). This will mostly consist of temorary allocated objects

(1) is mostly to find memory leaks / understand heap consumtion

(2) is most usable to profile performance as object allocation cost performance directly and indirectly (fragmentation, more gc's). Also in case of memleaks this can give you an indication where objects causing a memleak come from.